# Mylyn type plugin for Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, mylyn

[Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) is a task oriented plugin that allows for example to assign a set of files to a task. Is there a Mylyn type plugin for Visual Studio?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Tasktop has just announced that it is bringing the productivity of Mylyn into Visual Studio!  The beta version that is being released will support bringing tasks from HP ALM, Quality Center, and Bugzilla.  It includes Mylyn's **Task List** and **Task Editor**. The next level of support, which will include compatibility with all existing Mylyn connectors, will be delivered after this beta.  Further down the road Tasktop will also be delivering context capture and focus within the Visual Studio IDE.

The beta release will be happening end of November 2010.

See the recent [blog post](http://tasktop.com/blog/tasktop/eclipse-mylyn-microsoft-visual-studio) for more details.

David Shepherd, Tasktop Technologies 
http://www.twitter.com/davidcshepherd

Comment: I gather you're an experienced Mylyn user, sorry for giving you information you already knew!  You're right, there is currently no schedule for porting Mylyn to VS.  I will update this entry if I hear of any updates to this plan.

Comment: Maybe not an experienced user. Definitely a great fan though and as I work in VS most of the time those days I'm missing its functionality a lot

Comment: @David: could you keep this post updated? I'm looking forward to the full version :) We are using version one at work.

BTW you are pointing to this question in your announcement. Can it result in a free licence? :]

Comment: FYI, the GA of Tasktop for Visual Studio is out! https://tasktop.com/products/visual-studio/

Answer (score 3):

The closest I've found is [Tasktop](http://tasktop.com/products/), by the people that created Mylyn, but it's a standalone application that doesn't integrate with Visual Studio.

(Resharper is irrelevant).

Comment: Note that since this answer was posted Tasktop has released Mylyn support for Visual Studio. See my answer on this page.

Answer (score 2):

Not even close to mylyn, but here is an open source addin for visual studio that helps to assign a list of source files to a "session" (you could think of the session as a "task")

http://dsmaddin.codeplex.com/

Comment: Note that since this answer was posted Tasktop has released Mylyn support for Visual Studio.  See my answer on this page.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not aware of anything open source but i do know that team system is setup to support this type of workflow.

resharper might also have features you are looking for but, again, not foss

Answer (score 1):

I asked that question to the VS.NET Development team in Teched 2008.

She said that they've notice about Mylyn, but are still looking on it.
Task focusing plugin is not yet ready in VS.NET environment.

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in this news from Tasktop: http://tasktop.com/blog/tasktop/eclipse-mylyn-microsoft-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

I'll second tasktop. The newest version especially looks nice. Like orip said, it doesn't provide VS integration, but there's a Firefox extension which should be pretty nice... beats using Eclipse purely for Mylyn.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently released (commercial) [Task Canvas](https://vlasovstudio.com/task-canvas/) extension for Visual Studio 2015 that supports tasks with assigned sets of documents and code fragments.