# Visual Studio Context

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mylyn

In Eclipse we are using Mylyn to have an overview of our Trac Tickets. A nice feature is the Context attached to a Ticket. For example it remembers the classes you worked on when that ticket was active. If you open that ticket a month later, then Mylyn opens all the classes.

Is there something similar in Visual Studio?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mylyn type plugin for Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221809/mylyn-type-plugin-for-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio saves the files you have open to the project settings when you close the project/solution. The next time you open it, these will be open per default. VS does not contain the exact behaviour you describe, but you could search for a plugin that'll do this for you, or write it yourself.